# SFTP Help. Save a file in C#

Tags: c#, file

I am trying to save a sftp file in C#. I have [found this example on SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx) but I cannot get it to work on my application (in fact, i get an error whenever I try to use `SaveFileDialog` saying it doesn't exist and I cannot resolve the issue)

**Is this the right way to save a file? I am not clicking a button, but getting an sftp file from another location, and saving it locally so I can execute some commands on it.**

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 if that helps.

**Edit:** I think I confused people with the example that I found. Here is how I am getting the files:

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
   Sftp sftp = new AmexSFTP.src.Sftp(Config.sSFTPUrl,
                                     Config.sSFTPAccount,
                                     Config.sSFTPPasswd);
   // Connect to SFTP server
   sftp.Connect();

   List<string> InputFiles = sftp.GetFileList("output");

   //Save files in for each loop here...
  ....}

    public Sftp(string sftpHost, string user, string password)
        : base(sftpHost, user, password)
    {
        Init();
    }

    private void Init()
    {
        m_monitor = new MyProgressMonitor(this);
    }

    public List<string> GetFileList(string path)
    {
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry in SftpChannel.ls(path))
        {
            list.Add(entry.getFilename().ToString());
        }
        return list.ToList();
    }
```

Maybe SaveFileDialog is not correct? It was what I found for all my google results, so I assumed it was.

Thanks!

Comment: Does OpenFile actually create a file then?

Comment: Do you want the user to see a dialog, or can you just save the file without input from the user?

Comment: @James- I want to save the file without user input. The files are saved on another sftp site that I want to access. 
@mtijn- I use this code to get the files: `List<string>list = new List<string>();foreach (Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.ChannelSftp.LsEntry entry in SftpChannel.ls(path)){list.Add(entry.getFilename().ToString());}return list.ToList();`

Comment: It looks like your question has nothing to do with SFTP. The error is with saving the file to your local drive, right?

Comment: do you have enough rights to save the file or open the file properly?s

Comment: I don't think that was the right approach. I edited the question. Sorry about that, I just assumed SaveFileDialog was the way to go

Comment: @Phil - Yes, that is what I want to do here

Comment: I don't know these libraries you're using but it looks as if you're getting just filenames. is that enough info to save the file?

Comment: I was assuming that I would get the file path (along with name) then use that to go and actually retrieve the file. I haven't done any work with this situation though, so I may be overlooking something here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confusing things a bit. Unless I am mistaken the Page_Load() method is part of an ASP.NET WebForms project. If that's the case then you are mixing technologies: SaveFileDialog is a WinForms control which is normally used for client applications, not a web pages's code-behind code.